# PHP: How is this library intercepting curl functions?

Tags: php, curl, monkeypatching, php-vcr

I'm using a library called [PHP-VCR](https://github.com/php-vcr/php-vcr) for mocking HTTP requests in my tests. I see that this library intercepts curl methods (e.g. `curl_init`, `curl_setopts`, etc.), and I'm using it successfully, but I'm not following the actual intercepting or monkey-patching mechanism of it.

In the following stack trace, it goes from `curl_init` being called in `Stripe\..\CurlClient` to `VCR\...\CurlHook::curl_init`. How is this jump made?

[image: Interception]

Comment: Without studying it all, it would eventually be using [namespace fallback policy](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php), I can see it mangles the namespace of the caller, which fails autoloading, then it falls back to the namespace its called in (the test) then the lib re builds the request and does its own curl call. For the most part you can see that in [VCRFactory #38](https://github.com/php-vcr/php-vcr/blob/master/src/VCR/VCRFactory.php#L138)... [php-mock](https://github.com/php-mock/php-mock) does something similar, but for any inbuilt function

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for the response! I'm gonna have to look into that class a bit. I'm familiar with overriding PHP function with namespaces, but I haven't figured out how this lib does it.

Comment: Actually the magic happens in the test itself, in the example if you did `$result = \file_get_contents('http://example.com');` it wouldn't catch it, because your explicity setting the global namspace for fgc, as-is its actully internally called as `\VCRTest\file_get_contents()` till it fails and falls back to global, its that fallback which the lib catches in its mangling as mentioned before.